# Regular expression that contains one expression yet doesn't contain the other

Tags: regex, regex-negation

We are currently matching "service_hub*queue"
I want to ignore the case "service_hub_scout_dead_queue" and yet still match everything else.
What is the regular expression for that ?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "service_hub.*queue" ?

Answer (score 4):

This javascript sollution gives an array with the matches

```
var myText = 'service_hub_anything_queue Add service_hub_scout_dead_queue something service_hub_someting_queue else';
var myMatches = myText.match(/service_hub(?!_scout_dead_)\w+queue/g);
```

If you are rather interested in what follows a match

```
var mySplit = ('dummy'+myText).split(/service_hub(?!_scout_dead_)\w+queue/g).filter(function(txt,i) {return (i>0);})
```

I put 'dummy' and then filter away the first part to make it work both if the sting starts with a valid tag and when it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Using negative lookbehind: `"service_hub_.*?(?<!_scout_dead)_queue"`

This appears to be [widely supported](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) by popular regex engines; I've tested with Java (or Scala, rather) just to make sure it works.